# Check if date/time is BETWEEN two other date/times Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

```
var startDateTime = '15.04.2019 00:15';
var endDateTime = '17.05.2019 18:35';

var checkDateTime = '16.04.2019 13:15';

function(checkDateTime, startDateTime, endDateTime) {

// need codes to return true or false,.
// check "checkDateTime" is between "startDateTime" to "endDateTime"

}
```

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:momentjs]; did you try using it?

Comment: Very similar to: [13291661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291661/check-if-a-date-within-in-range). Almost a dupe.

Comment: Possible dupe of [48405762](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405762/js-check-if-multiple-dates-are-within-range). If the array of dates were size 1...that would answer this..

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (And no, having an empty function does not count)

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
var startDateTime = getDate('15.04.2019 00:15');
var endDateTime = getDate('17.05.2019 18:35');

var checkDateTime = getDate('16.04.2019 13:15');

function isBetween(checkDateTime, startDateTime, endDateTime) {

    return (checkDateTime >= startDateTime &&  checkDateTime <= endDateTime);

}

function toDate(str){
  var [ dd, MM, yyyy, hh, mm ] = str.split(/[. :]/g);
  return new Date(`${MM}/${dd}/${yyyy} ${hh}:${mm}`);
}

console.log(isBetween(checkDate,startDate,endDate));
```

---

To compare it one time falls between a time interval on the same day use: -

```
var startTime = "00:35";
var endTime = "18:15";
var checkTime = "13:00";

function getMinutes(timeString){
    let [hh, mm] = timeString.split(":");
    return parseInt(hh)*60 + parseInt(mm);
}

function isTimeBetween(checkTime,startTime,endTime){
      checkTime = getMinutes(checkTime);
      return (checkTime >= getMinutes(startTime) && checkTime <= getMinutes(endTime));
}
console.log(isTimeBetween(checkTime,startTime,endTime));
```

Comment: if I want to check only time span ?

Comment: @Mizhar Raja timespan between which dates, between checkDate and startDate or checkDate and endDate

Comment: There is no date. only startTime and endTime. need to check specific time is between or no.

Comment: var startTime = '00:15';
var endTime =  '18:35';

var checkTime = '13:15';

function isBetween(checkTime, startTime, endTime) { 
// need code to check
}

Comment: @Mizhar Raja Check out the time under time interval code. May be this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use new Date().getTime() to get the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch. So that you can compared the date/time with the result from this function. You can do sth like that:

```
return new Date(startDateTime).getTime() <= new Date(checkDateTime).getTime() <= new Date(endDateTime).getTime();
```

Check this out: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: Almost.. When I test this function, it also returns true if the date is out of the range. When I set `checkDateTime` to '06/16/2019 13:15' (out of range), the function returns `true`, but should be `false`. I think the conditional just needs to be separated by an &&.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check if your checkDateTime is greater than your startDateTime and less then endDateTime.

```js
function checkDateTime(checkDateTime, startDateTime, endDateTime) {
  return (new Date(startDateTime) >= new Date(checkDateTime))
      && (new Date(checkDateTime) <= new Date(endDateTime));
}
```

Comment: If you go for this solution, I would also recommend to store `new Date(checkDateTime)` in a variable to improve the performance.
I left it out by intention to avoid any unnecessary confusion

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another option which adds the method directly to the Date prototype:

```js
var startDateTime = new Date('04/15/2019 00:15');
var endDateTime = new Date('05/17/2019 18:35');

var checkDateTime = new Date('04/16/2019 13:15');
var outOfRangeDate_EARLY = new Date('01/16/2019 13:15');
var outOfRangeDate_LATE = new Date('06/16/2019 13:15');

Date.prototype.inRange = function(startDate, endDate){
  var this_ms = this.getTime();
  return ( this_ms >= startDate.getTime() && this_ms <= endDate.getTime() )
}

/* Tests */
console.log('expected: true', 'actual:', checkDateTime.inRange(startDateTime, endDateTime))
console.log('expected: false', 'actual:', outOfRangeDate_EARLY.inRange(startDateTime, endDateTime))
console.log('expected: false', 'actual:', outOfRangeDate_LATE.inRange(startDateTime, endDateTime))
```

This way, with any date you have `var someDate`, you can just call `someDate.inRange(startDate, endDate)`. Sometimes, however, messing with the native prototypes can come back to haunt you if not careful. If so, having a separate function as answered by the others is very good.

Lastly, it's very important that the date strings are formatted properly before creating the `Date` objects, otherwise you'll encounter `Invalid Date` a lot. I hope this helps.